# How do i find character (variable) from a string?

Tags: c++, string, character

```
cin >> letter >> position; //This is inside the main(). 

void moveLetter(char letter, int position) {`

    if (upperRowPiecesToPlay.find(letter)) {

        upperRowPiecesToPlay.replace(letter,1 , " ");

            switch(position) {

                case 1:
                    if(p1 == '.' ) {
                    p1 = letter;
                    }

                    break;
```

So, this is my code.

I'd like to find a character(input from a user) from the given string. And replace it with empty space.

However, obviously this is not how I should use the find and replace.

Please teach me the right way...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now all we can do is guess at what `upperRowPiecesToPlay` is (presumably `std::string`) and what `p1` is (presumably `char`). What isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the return value of [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) correctly.

`std::string::find()` returns the *index* of the specified character, or `std::string::npos` (-1) if not found.  It does not return a `bool`, like your code seems to think it does.

When an `if` statement is evaluated, a non-zero integer value is treated as true.  Which means your code will try to execute `upperRowPiecesToPlay.replace()` if the `letter` is found at any index *other than 0*, or *is not found at all*.

But there is no overload of [`std::string::replace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) that will take the `letter` as input.  You need to instead give it the index that `find()` returns, if it is not `npos`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void moveLetter(char letter, int position)
{
    std::string::size_type index = upperRowPiecesToPlay.find(letter);
    if (index != std::string::npos) {
        upperRowPiecesToPlay.replace(index, 1 , " ");
        // alternatively:
        // upperRowPiecesToPlay[index] = ' ';
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: alternative2: `upperRowPiecesToPlay.at(index) = ' '`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `std::string::at()` performs bounds checking, `std::string::operator[]` does not. The `index` in this example is already guaranteed to be in-bounds by the `if` (assuming `upperRowPiecesToPlay` is not being modified by other thread), so `at()` would just be wasted overhead. It would make sense to use `at()` only if the `if` is omitted.

Comment: Yes, true, that's why `upperRowPiecesToPlay.at(upperRowPiecesToPlay.find(letter)) = ' '` would work in one-shot.